# What is the difference between Firebase cloud messaging types from latency and security perspectives?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

When we are talking about individual private push notifications **per user** (rather than per device), there are couple of ways to send them via Firebase:

1. Collect registration tokens, associate them with the user on the trusted server and send notifications to all registered tokens.
2. Assign a topic per user, e.g. topics/user-id and let the app subscribe to it upon successful login / unsubscribe on logout.

However, Firebase documentation recommends to use approach no. 1, saying ["For fast, secure delivery to single devices or small groups of devices, target messages to registration tokens, not topics."](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging)

One concern is the latency (referring to "fast") issue. Is it really that significant in practice comparing registration tokens vs topics-based messaging?

More serious concern is security.
What does Firebase documentation mean exactly by "... secure delivery..." as opposed to topics?

In our case one device will likely be used by multiple users logging in and out. That means registration tokens will have to be disassociated from the user in the backend when user logs out. If something goes wrong and registration token is not disassociated, device will continue getting previous person's notifications.

Is this the trade-off I have to accept or am I missing some other option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few questions in there. Let's see if I can cover them main ones.

---

If you need to **deliver messages to multiple tokens**, the two approaches you're considering are:

1. Subscribe the app installs/tokens to a specific topic, that you then deliver the message to.
2. Keep your own registry of tokens for the user, and do the fan-out of user-to-tokens in your own code.

The biggest difference is in where the fan-out of a user to their tokens happens. When you use topics it is done by Firebase on Google's servers, while in the second case you do it yourself. There is no guaranteed performance difference between these two, but in the latter case you have more control. So you spend more effort (writing your own code for something Firebase can do for you), and in turn gain more control (which may or may not translate into better performance)..

---

The second question is around the **security of topics**. The documentation contains that note because topics often have a much simpler structure than tokens. For example, if you have a topic-per-user, you will often use the UID as the topic ID. And since you may be sharing that UID in other places, it is possible that other users may know a user's UID. And since subscribing to a topic only requires that you know your own token and the topic ID, that means that any user can subscribe to another user's topic.

Comment: It raised another question, is it possible at some point to get all the registration tokens subscribed to a particular topic?
Thank you for clearing it up!

Comment: There is no public API to get the list of tokens for a topic.